# Calculate BJT Temperature when the output connect to 16V

Tags: temperature, bjt

[image: Short Circuit Test]

Hi,

Would need a help on how to calculate the BJT's Temperature when the "L" Output was connect to 16VDC?

Need to know the Temperature dissipation of the BJT on calculation.

Thanks
Lee

Comment: This would be much easier if you measure the actual voltage in the collector of the transistor (TP2) so that the current and Vce drop can be calculated rather than guessed.

Comment: We can't see where R9 is connected, and the answer depends on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the temperature in two steps. First, analyze the circuit to find the voltage on the collector of Q1. Assuming TP2 goes not go anywhere to the right, the current into the collector of Q1 is \$I_c = \$ \$  (8V - V_c) \over 150 \$ + \$ (16V - V_c) \over 68 \$, and the collector power dissipation is \$P_d = I_c \cdot V_c \$. Usually we can ignore the base power dissipation, but if you want you can calculate the current into the base and find \$I_b \cdot V_{BE}\$
for the base dissipation, then add \$P_{d(base)}\$ + \$P_{d(collector)}\$ to get \$P_{d(total)}\$.

The steady-state junction temperature of Q1 can be approximated by: 
\$T_J = T_A + P_d \cdot R_{\theta JA} \$, where \$R_{\theta JA}\$ is the junction-to-ambient thermal resistance, and \$T_A\$ is the ambient temperature.

\$R_{\theta JA}\$ can typically be found in the datasheet. Below is an NXP datasheet snippet. 
[image]

Note the units of kelvins per watt, as electrical resistance could be described as volts per ampere.

The calculation of steady-state temperature with an assumed Newtonian heat flow is analogous to Ohm's law (a constant thermal resistance). It's only accurate where convection cooling and radiative cooling do not dominate, because the latter two mechanisms are quite non-linear.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us enough information to go on but

- If we assume the transistor is totally off then the voltage at the collector would be

$$\frac{16V \cdot 150 \Omega + 8V \cdot 68 \Omega}{68 \Omega + 150 \Omega}= 13.504V$$

There would be no current in the collector so no power dissipation and the junction temperature would be the same as the ambient.

- If we  drive the transistor such as to get absolute maximum power dissipation in the transistor then the transistor will need to have an resistance equal to 68ohm in parallel with 150ohm = 46.788ohm.  The power dissipation will be

$$\frac{(13.504V)^2}{4 \times 46.788 \Omega}= 0.974W$$

The thermal resistance (junction to air) is 500K/W which would mean the junction should be 487deg C above ambient but it won't be because the transistor will have failed and gone short circuit.

- If the transistor is hard on then it will have collector current (8/150)+(16/68)=289mA.  The saturated collector emitter voltage will be better than 0.1 volt giving a power dissipation of less than 28.9mW and the junction temperature will be less than 14.43 degrees above ambient.